# What are the differences between early access and finished versions of Zweihänder?

Tags: edition-comparison, zweihander

What are the differences between early access and finished versions Zweihänder grim & perilous rpg? What has been changed? What has been added or removed?

[As early access version I mean the latest one.](http://drivethrurpg.com/product/192264/ZWEIHANDER-Grim--Perilous-RPG-EARLY-ACCESS-v2)

Comment: Wait. Wait. [*Zweihänder*](https://grimandperilous.com/what-is-zweihander/) is a *darker* and *grittier* version of *Warhammer Fantasy Role-play*? I am stunned that such a thing is even possible… and am now interested. I mean, what, can your character now die *before* character creation?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The only darker and grittier option beyond that would be players dying during character creation. :)

Comment: I mean, I can check later. To be sure, we're talking about the original PDF copy of the early access rules they gave out from the Kickstarter, followed by the full print edition? AFAIK, Zweihander was also playtested for a good few years before the KS even launched, so there are likely multiple versions of "early access" rules floating out there.